# Where we are passing labels to CNN Image Classifier?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, label, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I have a simple&basic question. When we are training an image classifier model(ie with CNN) exactly where we are telling the model this is a cat or a dog? Before backpropagation, the model knows that it is a dog or a cat because it is arranging new weights accordingly.
Our data is labelled but we are not reading or passing this information to the network. I am working with image captioning which is much more complicated. I appreciate any clarification, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is used in the loss (aka cost) function. When you give an image as an input to a network and some output is activated, the difference between the output and the truth is called loss. So, the optimization algorithm tries to minimize these losses by changing weights.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question is, when I started to train the model with a cat picture, how model knows this is a cat, I only uploaded the picture.

Comment: If you are not giving labels at some point then you are not training it. The loss function MUST have the truth to calculate the loss (to optimize). Probably somewhere in the code, it is passing. It helps if you show your code.

Comment: I added to the picture to the post, there are two folders under training_set, which are cat and dog. I believe while it is reading from the folder, it is also labelling all the picture under cat folder as a cat. But I am not sure.

Comment: That' right. You see the output of the cell that says "training_set = ...". The output says "found 5319 images belonging to 2 classes". It means Keras inferred labels based on the directory structure. It doesn't make any difference what the labels are. It will call them 0 and 1 (instead of cat and dog).

Comment: You can read more here: https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class